# Data format needs to be corrected as per the requirement

Tags: java, cucumber

I have a requirement where i have got the below sentence coming in below format which is not the right format:

When user log in When user clicks button And user enters data |data1||data2||11||44|
This sentence needs to come in below format via code.

```
When user log in 
When user clicks button
And user enters data
|data1||data2|
|11||44|
```

Not getting the way I would reach to the requirement.Is there a way by which i can achieve the above?

Tried with the below logic:

```
String str="When user log in When user clicks button And user enters data |data1||data2||11||44|";

if(str.contains("When") || str.contains("And")){
 String[] st=str.split(" ");
for(String st:str)){
System.out.println(st);
}
```

But the output is like every single word of that sentence is getting printed in a new line.

```
When user log in 
When user clicks button
And user enters data
|data1||data2|
|11||44|
When user logout
And user fill form
|data1||data2|
|11|44|
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way you can achieve this , you can check

```
 String text = "When user log in When user clicks button And user enters data |data1||data2||11||44|";

    int start = 0;
    int end = text.lastIndexOf("When");

    int start1 = end;
    int end1 = text.lastIndexOf("And");

    int start2 = end1;
    int end2 = text.lastIndexOf("|data1|");

    int start3 = end2;
    int end3 = text.lastIndexOf("|11|");

    int start4 = end3;
    int end4 = text.lastIndexOf("");

    String line1 = (String) text.subSequence(start, end);
    String line2 = (String) text.subSequence(start1, end1);
    String line3 = (String) text.subSequence(start2, end2);
    String line4 = (String) text.subSequence(start3, end3);
    String line5 = (String) text.subSequence(start4, end4);


    System.out.println(line1+"\n"+line2+"\n"+line3+"\n"+line4+"\n"+line5);
```

Comment: I cannot hard code |data1| and |11| as there would be multiple sentences as there would be multiple sentences like below:When user log in When user clicks button And user enters data |data1||data2||11||44| When user logout And fill form |data5|data6|7||10|.So whenver any When, And , or any data table starts like|data1||data2||11||44| it should be coming as shown in post above.